# ObjectDisposedException when triggering UI events from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

Currently I have a project which includes some WinForms bindings to allow operating the interface not only with the mouse, but also through an external hardware device.

The external device is interfaced through a DLL which allows subscribing to hardware button push events, which are being sent from a separate thread.

Here is how the class I've made for the buttons looks like (details omitted):

```cs
public class PanelBoundButton : Button, IPanelBoundControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets what hardware button the control is bound to.
        /// </summary>
        [Description("Panel button to bind"), Category("Hardware Interface")]
        public HardwareButtonFlags Binding
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        // For debouncing
        private DateTime pressTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        private const int DEBOUNCE_MS = 100;

        public void Bind()
        {
            if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;
            ButtonReader.ButtonsChanged += new EventHandler<HardwareButtonEvent>(HardwareHandleButtonChange);
        }

        public void Unbind()
        {
            if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;
            ButtonReader.ButtonsChanged -= HardwareHandleButtonChange;
        }

        // External hardware button event handler
        void HardwareHandleButtonChange(object sender, HardwareButtonEvent e)
        {
            if (this.Binding != 0 && e.Released.HasFlag(this.Binding) && this.Enabled)
            {
                if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(pressTime).TotalMilliseconds < DEBOUNCE_MS)
                {
                    Logger.Log("Button event seems like noise, ignoring for debouncing");
                    return;
                }
                pressTime = DateTime.Now;
                Action clk = delegate()
                {
                    this.PerformClick();
                };
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    this.Invoke(clk);
                else clk();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, sometimes when operating the button, in particular the one which closes the form, users are getting a crash with the following stack trace. Originally I thought it may be because of the button press being recognized twice, hence the debouncing part of the code above, but it didn't help (and the debounce line is never logged, either).

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'AppOperationSelectorTabPages'.
Happened in object: System.Windows.Forms
Happened in method: System.Object MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control, System.Delegate, System.Object[], Boolean)
     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at projectname.GUI.PanelBoundButton.HardwareHandleButtonChange(Object sender, HardwareButtonEvent e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at projectIoLib.FrontPanel.ButtonReader.OnButtonEvent(Object sender, HardwareButtonEvent e)
   at projectIoLib.FrontPanel.ButtonEventEmitter._ButtonCheckingThread()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

However, from this stack trace I cannot really determine, which object was disposed at the time of access? Was it my button? Or was it that TabPages object?

Moreover, currently unbinding the button is handled by the form when it's closed. However my guess is that happens late enough for the crash to occur.
Am I missing an override of some method (like `Dispose`) in my button class to unsubscribe from the hardware events before it becomes fatal to handle them?

Comment: Whatever class owns the handle to the device needs to implement idisposable

Comment: If you try to access UI objects when the Form is closed, you get that exception. `InvokeRequired`, `IsHandleCreated`, `IsDisposed` won't help: your Thread /Task won't be able to read those values effectively. You have to signal the Task/Thread that it's time to terminate, then complete the closing procedure. I.e., avoid to have anything running that is bound to access UI elements when the Parent Container is being closed/disposed of.

Comment: @Jimi However, my custom control isn't getting any events about when the parent is destroyed. Would implementing IDisposable and unsubscribing from hardware events in there efficiently remediate this, or is there a special event to override in order to know when the parent form is destroyed?

Comment: UserControls implement IDisposable by design. You have `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` in `Designer.cs` (you can move it to the code file if needed). You can also override `OnHandleDestroyed`. When this method is called, your UC and its `ParentForm` still have a Handle (`IsHandleCreated = true`). When `Dispose()` is called, both the UC and its `ParentForm` don't have a handle anymore, but the UC (`this`) and its fields are still available (you can dispose of objects that hold unmanaged resources, as Bitmaps, here). Note that `OnHandleDestroyed` is also called at design-time.

Comment: @Jimi I don't have a `Designer.cs` for my control, may that be the culprit that it's not implemented? It's not a User Control in the traditional sense, just a subclass of Button.

Comment: @Jimi yup, I just did that and placed a call to the unbind routine along with a fallthrough to `base` in there. Locally it works fine, so now gotta deploy and see if that stops the crashes from happening.

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous comment wasn't actually directed to you, but to a very similar active question with a very similar setup and I mixed these up (the nickname is also ~similar). In a Custom Control, you can override `Dispose` (`protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { if (disposing) {...} base.Dispose(disposing); }`). This is called when the Control is being disposed of. The other methods previously mentioned nonetheless apply. -- You of course can split your code in different *files*, making `public class PanelBoundButton` a partial class as the standard designer does.